# Why is my Excel declaration crashing my file?

Tags: excel, vba, crash, function-declaration

I have an Excel file that used to run fine in Excel 365 that now crashes.  I've traced it down to a single line of code in my declarations section in my VBA code:

```vb
Private Declare Function apiShowWindow Lib "user32" Alias "ShowWindow" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
```

Here's the question:  ***just pasting this line of code into a brand-new Excel file causes a crash***--when I try to save the file I get sharing violations, access violations, etc., etc.  Even trying something like this:

```vb
#If VBA7 Then

Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiShowWindow Lib "user32" Alias "ShowWindow" _
    (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

#Else

Private Declare Function apiShowWindow Lib "user32" Alias "ShowWindow" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

#End If
```

doesn't solve the problem.  Can someone help?  Again--**just putting the single line of code in a new file causes the crash when saving**, whether or not I've set Trust Center to enable or disable all macros.

Comment: **What is the error number or message**.?  Windows tells you what you are doing wrong via error codes.

Answer (score 2):

### Windows API

- You cannot rename an API function, its name is fixed. It is searched for in a library, in this case in `user32.dll`.
- The following is working correctly on my machine `Win 10 64bit Office 2019 64bit`.

```vb
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow _
        Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function ShowWindow _
        Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
#End If
```

- You could do something like this...

```vb
Sub apiShowWindow(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long)
    ShowWindow hwnd, nCmdShow
End Sub
```

... and use it e.g. like this...

```
Sub test()
    apiShowWindow Windows(1).hwnd, 0
End Sub
```

... though.

Or as a function:

```
Function api2ShowWindow(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
    api2ShowWindow = ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow)
End Function

Sub test2()
    Debug.Print api2ShowWindow(Windows(1).hwnd, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi--Thanks for the suggestion.  However, I pasted your code in exactly as you have it, and I'm still getting errors.  "Excel can't save the file", "Errors were detected while saving..." and so on.